# how to get my application directory name

Tags: cakephp

my url is http://localhost/myAppliation/....

I want to get the "myApplication". Which is the key word to get the value?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want:

```
$this->webroot
```

or

```
$this->base
```

or

```
$this->here
```

in your controller. See http://api.cakephp.org/class/controller for definition of this variables.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Didn't see that you were using CakePHP. If you weren't using any frameworks, you would get the path via this:

First you need to reconstruct the URL.

```
$pageURL = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80")
{
    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
} 
else 
{
    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}
```

Then parse it for the path.

```
$parts = parse_url($pageURL);
$path = $parts['path'];
```

After that if you want to only get the first path, explode it on '/', strip out the null values, and then the first one will be the first path, and so on.

```
$paths = explode('/', $path);
foreach($paths as $key => $value)
{
    if(!empty($value))
    {
        $new_paths[] = $value;
    }
}
$first_path = $new_paths[0];
```

Comment: You have to do all that to get the name of your application?  Surely it's stored somewhere.

Comment: Thats for breaking up the path. If you are using a framework, you never mentioned it.

Comment: Ah .. never saw the cakephp part. You should mention that in the question. I'll make it clear that mine is for breaking up the path since I don't know much about CakePHP.

Answer (score 0):

There is something called the $Name attribute, but I'm not sure if that gives you the application name.  The CakePHP manual says:

> PHP4 users should start out their
>   controller definitions using the $name
>   attribute. The $name attribute should
>   be set to the name of the controller.
>   Usually this is just the plural form
>   of the primary model the controller
>   uses. This takes care of some PHP4
>   classname oddities and helps CakePHP
>   resolve naming.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/52/name

Answer (score 0):

http://book.cakephp.org/view/317/Cake-s-Global-Constants-And-Functions

I think you want to use the WEBROOT_DIR constant.