# How to know webroot in core.php

Tags: cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 2.3.1.

Our server has some independent applications in one server. So I want to change `session.cookie_path` setting following the [Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html) :

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'ini' => array(
        'session.cookie_path' => '/app/dir'
    )
));
```

I could change it successfully with this. But here is a problem. I need to set `session.cookie_path` value to `webroot` dynamically (without string literal value such as `'/app/dir'`).

I've tried to use `$this->webroot` following [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182512/how-to-get-my-application-directory-name), but of course it does not work because there is no controller in the file `app/Config/core.php`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I realized a php variable is available : `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.
So I could solve the problem.

```
$requestURI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$webroot = preg_replace('/(^\/[^\/]+\/).*$/', '$1', $requestURI);
//echo $webroot;
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'cake',
    'ini' => array(
        'session.cookie_path' => $webroot   // looks like '/app/'
    )
));
```

But this solution does not have reusability enough : it would not work for apps located in deeper directories such as `/apps/app1/`.

I'm still awaiting a better solution.